# How do I put multiple variables into a SQL query

Tags: python, sql

For example

```
a = input("first digit:")
b = input("second digit:")
c = input("third digit:")
c.execute("INSERT INTO batch VALUES a, b, c")
```

yet, this doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please describe your problem in more detail. The sql statement is fine https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
 c.execute("INSERT INTO batch VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (a,b,d))
```

make sure you don't use c again, since you are using it as a cursor as well. This changes your `c = connection.cursor()` to `c = ("input")`